# How to set the windows to open IE or Edge browser, automatically connected to the VPN service?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, vpn

How to set the windows to open IE or Edge browser, automatically connected to the VPN service?

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can either write a batch file to connect to VPN when IE starts or just try to enable VPN Auto-Triggering feature.

It's an example of how to setup the VPN auto connect task in Windows Task Scheduler: http://www.buchatech.com/2011/04/configure-windows-to-automatically-connect-to-vpn/

And these are the materials on VPN Auto-Triggering functionality: 
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2013/10/02/automatically-triggering-vpn-connections-and-vpn-diagnostics-enhancements-in-windows-8-1/

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2016/01/25/step-by-step-enabling-apps-to-auto-trigger-vpns-in-windows-10/

Hope it helps.